# Custom field name mapping in expressionengine

Tags: expressionengine, custom-fields

I am making some changes to a site using ExpressionEngine, there is a concept I can't seem to quite understand and am probably coding workarounds that have pre-provided methods.

Specifically with channels and members, the original creator has added several custom fields.  I am from a traditional database background where each column in a table has a specific meaningful name.  I am also used to extending proprietary data by adding a related table joined with a unique key, again, field names in the related table are meaningful.

However, in EE, when you add custom fields, it creates them in the table as field_id_x and puts an entry into another table telling you what these are.

Now this is all nice from a UI point of view for giving power to an administrator but this is a total headache when writing any code.

Ok, there's template tags but I tend not to use them and they are no good in a database query anyway.

Is there a simple way to do a query on say the members table and then address m_field_1 as what its really called - in my case "addresslonglat".

There are dozens of these fields in the table I am working on and at the moment I am addressing them with fixed names like "m_field_id_73" which means nothing.

Anybody know of an easy way to bring the data and its field names together easily?

Ideally i'd like to do the following:

```
$result = $this->EE->db->query("select * from exp_member_data where member_id = 123")->row();
echo $result->addresslonglat;
```

Rather than

```
echo $result->m_field_id_73;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php    
$fields = $data = array();
$member_fields = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT m_field_id, m_field_name FROM exp_member_fields");
foreach($member_fields->result_array() as $row)
{
    $fields['m_field_id_'.$row['m_field_id']] = $row['m_field_name'];
}

$member_data = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_member_data WHERE member_id = 1")->row();
foreach($member_data as $k => $v)
{       
    if($k != 'member_id')
    {
        $data[$fields[$k]] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($data);
?>
```

Then just use your new `$data` array.

Comment: Perfect, could I then extend EE's DB class to override the row() and result() array methods to do this automatically, is there a way to ensure my version of DB would get loaded to extend the EE version that's an extension of the CodeIgniter version?

Comment: I wouldn't do that, since this code is for the member fields specifically ... seems overkill. If you're using this inside an add-on (which is hopefully the case), and want to keep things DRY, just wrap the field mapping into a function and pass your results to it (e.g., $data = $this->_map_member_fields($member_data);)

Comment: Thank you Derek, I just wish that they made it a little more obvious in EE how to handle custom fields from the developer's perspective.  I don't think EE's database is particularly well managed as it just adds columns rather than properly managing the table.